# Animation Won't Start at certain frame

Tags: animation, keyframes, gltf

I recently downloaded an animation file from Sketchfab. When I imported it as an fbx file, it wouldn't play, so I downloaded it as a glTF file and the animation plays fine. I want the animation to start at a specific frame, but I can't figure out how to do that. There are no keyframes in the animation timeline. When I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Pos 1</kbd> to place the start frame, the animation is cut off, and everything else I've tried doesn't seem to work.

Comment: pls provide blend file because you didn't give us any information of your animation setup

Comment: Here's the original sketchfab page, https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/poppy-playtime-huggy-wuggy-walk-animation-3914ed4d04ae44159aea26b1846f87ba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open NLA Editor, select this object here:

[image]

then you will see:

[image]

now press pushdown:

[image]

you will get:

[image]

now move the action as desired: (mouse drag the unlocked)

[image]

result:

[image]

i would recommend watching some NLA editor tutorials - unfortunately it isn't intuitive, but if you learn it you will unleash its power...!